# IndexMissingException using Bonsai Elasticsearch with Heroku and Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-haystack, bonsai-elasticsearch

**Environment:** I am running Django==1.5.4 with Python 2.7.2, deploying to Heroku. I am using Haystack with Elastic Search. On Heroku I'm using the Bonsai Elastic Search add-on.

**Issue:** When I run the rebuild_index command, I encounter a "Read timeout error" when destroying the index and "IndexMissingException" when attempting to create the indexes. The log output is this:

```
> heroku run python manage.py rebuild_index
Running `python manage.py rebuild_index` attached to terminal... up, run.1762

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: Non-OK response returned (404): u'IndexMissingException[[msdc] missing]'
All documents removed.
Indexing 195 schools
ERROR:root:Error updating schools using default 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 221, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 267, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 89, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 183, in update
    self.conn.bulk_index(self.index_name, 'modelresult', prepped_docs, id_field=ID)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 96, in decorate
    return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 387, in bulk_index
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 254, in send_request
    self._raise_exception(resp, prepped_response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 268, in _raise_exception
    raise error_class(response.status_code, error_message)
ElasticHttpNotFoundError: (404, u'IndexMissingException[[msdc] missing]')
ElasticHttpNotFoundError: (404, u'IndexMissingException[[msdc] missing]')
```

**Verification:** I have created the index explicitely, which I have verified by trying to re-create it and running through the test steps:

```
> curl -X POST http://index@box.us-east-1.bonsai.io/msdc
{"error":"Index already exists.","status":400}%

> curl -X POST http://index@boc.us-east-1.bonsai.io/msdc/test -d '{"title":"hello, world"}'
{"ok":true,"_index":"msdc","_type":"test","_id":"9q8t4m0sTgy6JeGkueL54Q","_version":1}%   

> curl -X POST http://index@box.us-east-1.bonsai.io/msdc/_search -d '{}'                  
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"msdc","_type":"test","_id":"9q8t4m0sTgy6JeGkueL54Q","_score":1.0, "_source" : {"title":"hello, world"}}]}}%
```

I am fairly new to Elasticsearch and Heroku, so I may be missing a critical step. Any help troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated!